# Folding matrix rows element wise and computing average in Rust

Tags: vector, rust, iterator

Suppose I have to following matrix represented by `Vec<Vec<_>>`:

```
[[5, 9, 4],
 [8, 8, 2],
 [4, 5, 3]]
```

The number of rows / columns in unknown at compile time, but the rows are guaranteed to be of equal length.
I want to sum up all of the rows element wise and divide them by the number of rows (i.e., get the "mean column"). I also need to get the type `Vec<_>` at the end. I.e. the following:

```
[5.66, 7.33, 3] == [(5 + 8 + 4) / 3, (9 + 8 + 5) / 3, (4 + 2 + 3) / 3]
```

What is the most idiomatic way to do this in Rust? Preferably without using `ndarray` crate.

Comment: You're right! Sorry about that. Fixed the description and updated it with the random values to remove ambiguity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the inner `Vec` is a column, then you could [`fold()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) and [`sum()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) across.

```rust
fn col_means(mat: &[Vec<f64>]) -> Vec<f64> {
    assert!(!mat.is_empty());

    let col_len = mat[0].len();
    let mut col_means = mat.iter().fold(vec![0.0; col_len], |mut col_means, row| {
        row.iter()
            .enumerate()
            .for_each(|(i, cell)| col_means[i] += cell);
        col_means
    });
    for col in col_means.iter_mut() {
        *col /= col_len as f64;
    }

    col_means
}

fn main() {
    let mat: Vec<Vec<f64>> = vec![
        vec![5.0, 9.0, 4.0],
        vec![8.0, 8.0, 2.0],
        vec![4.0, 5.0, 3.0],
    ];

    let col_means = col_means(&mat);
    println!("{:?}", col_means);
    // Outputs `[5.666666666666667, 7.333333333333333, 3.0]`
}
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the inner `Vec` and then use [`chunks()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks), thus removing a layer of indirection.

```rust
fn col_means(mat: &[f64], col_len: usize) -> Vec<f64> {
    let mut col_means = mat
        .chunks(col_len)
        .fold(vec![0.0; col_len], |mut col_means, row| {
            row.iter()
                .enumerate()
                .for_each(|(i, cell)| col_means[i] += cell);
            col_means
        });
    for col in col_means.iter_mut() {
        *col /= col_len as f64;
    }

    col_means
}

fn main() {
    let mat: Vec<f64> = vec![5.0, 9.0, 4.0,
                             8.0, 8.0, 2.0,
                             4.0, 5.0, 3.0];

    let col_means = col_means(&mat, 3);
    println!("{:?}", col_means);
    // Outputs `[5.666666666666667, 7.333333333333333, 3.0]`
}
```

---

#### Old Answer

Assuming the inner `Vec` is a row. Then you can use a combination of [`iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter), [`sum()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) and then [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) into a `Vec`.

```rust
let mat: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![1, 2, 3], vec![2, 3, 4], vec![3, 4, 5]];

let row_means = mat
    .iter()
    .map(|row| row.iter().sum::<i32>() / (row.len() as i32))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();

println!("{:?}", row_means);
// Outputs `[2, 3, 4]`
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the inner `Vec` and then use [`chunks()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks), thus removing a layer of indirection.

```rust
let mat: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5];
let row_len = 3;

let row_means = mat
    .chunks(row_len as usize)
    .map(|row| row.iter().sum::<i32>() / row_len)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();

println!("{:?}", row_means);
// Outputs `[2, 3, 4]`
```

Then you could abstract and hide away the implementation into a reusable `struct Mat`.

```rust
struct Mat(usize, Vec<i32>);

impl Mat {
    fn row_means(&self) -> Vec<i32> {
        let row_len = self.row_len();
        self.1
            .chunks(row_len)
            .map(|row| row.iter().sum::<i32>() / (row_len as i32))
            .collect()
    }

    fn cell(&self, row: usize, col: usize) -> i32 {
        self.1[col + row * self.row_len()]
    }

    fn row_len(&self) -> usize {
        self.0
    }

    fn col_len(&self) -> usize {
        self.1.len() / self.row_len()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mat = Mat(3, vec![1, 2, 3,
                          2, 3, 4,
                          3, 4, 5]);
    println!("{:?}", mat.row_means());
    // Outputs `[2, 3, 4]`
}
```

Comment: Messed up the first one indeed. I've fixed it now. I usually consider `x_{count,size,len}` to be synonyms, but yeah, in this case I can see that `row_count` sounds wrong. I've renamed it to `row_len` to be more on par with Rust, compared to `row_size` :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to calculate the mean column of arbitrarily sized grids:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct EmptyGrid;

fn mean_column(grid: &[Vec<f64>]) -> Result<Vec<f64>, EmptyGrid> {
    if grid.is_empty() {
        return Err(EmptyGrid);
    }
    if grid[0].is_empty() {
        return Ok(Vec::new());
    }
    let mut mean = grid[0].to_vec();
    let col_len = mean.len();
    for row in grid.iter().skip(1) {
        for i in 0..col_len {
            mean[i] += row[i];
        }
    }
    let row_len = grid.len() as f64;
    for sum in mean.iter_mut() {
        *sum /= row_len;
    }
    Ok(mean)
}

fn main() {
    let grid = vec![
        vec![5.0, 9.0, 4.0],
        vec![8.0, 8.0, 2.0],
        vec![4.0, 5.0, 3.0],
    ];
    let mean_column = mean_column(&grid).unwrap();
    dbg!(mean_column); // prints [5.66, 7.33, 3.0]
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b999202eb955a8a79da251212d22337)